# error with map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

hello guys i wrote  2 classes one for the mapView and another for the location settings  and i use alertDialog box to make the user to choise between enable of GPS or going directly to the map  using intent but i face an error . any one can help ???

here is the dialog code

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Click yes TO ENABLE GPS")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, close
                                    // current activity
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);  
                                      startActivityForResult(intent, 1);  
                                      } 

                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                                    //dialog.cancel();

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AndroidGoogleMapsActivity.class);
                                    context.startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });



            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();

        }

    });
```

and here is the error that i got

```
09-19 08:28:58.996: W/dalvikvm(440): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mkyong/android/AndroidGoogleMapsActivity; (16)
09-19 08:28:58.996: W/dalvikvm(440): Link of class 'Lcom/mkyong/android/AndroidGoogleMapsActivity;' failed
09-19 08:28:59.004: E/dalvikvm(440): Could not find class 'com.mkyong.android.AndroidGoogleMapsActivity', referenced from method com.mkyong.android.MainActivity$1$2.onClick
09-19 08:28:59.004: W/dalvikvm(440): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 19 (Lcom/mkyong/android/AndroidGoogleMapsActivity;) in Lcom/mkyong/android/MainActivity$1$2;
09-19 08:28:59.004: D/dalvikvm(440): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0008
09-19 08:28:59.014: D/dalvikvm(440): VFY: dead code 0x000a-0018 in Lcom/mkyong/android/MainActivity$1$2;.onClick (Landroid/content/DialogInterface;I)V
09-19 08:29:16.164: D/AndroidRuntime(440): Shutting down VM
09-19 08:29:16.174: W/dalvikvm(440): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-19 08:29:16.254: E/AndroidRuntime(440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 08:29:16.254: E/AndroidRuntime(440): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mkyong.android.AndroidGoogleMapsActivity
09-19 08:29:16.254: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.mkyong.android.MainActivity$1$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:61)
09-19 08:29:16.254: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
09-19 08:29:16.254: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 08:29:16.254: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-19 08:29:16.254: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-19 08:29:16.254: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 08:29:16.254: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-19 08:29:16.254: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-19 08:29:16.254: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-19 08:29:16.254: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-19 08:29:18.725: I/Process(440): Sending signal. PID: 440 SIG: 9
```

I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you define the AndroidGoogleMapsActivity class and the maps library in your manifest file? You must put in within the  element.

```
<application ...>
...
<uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
...
</application>
```

Comment: By creating a new question for the new error it would be easier to be found by other than discussing it her in the comments.